# Why is R Shiny only showing side panel now?

Tags: shiny

Why is our data table not showing, only the panel with the two buttons?

```
library(openxlsx)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
df=read.xlsx("sayings.xlsx",sheet=1)
colnames(df)[2:3]<-c("English text","Original text")


ui <- fluidPage(
 
  
 titlePanel("Idioms and Sayings"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel( 
    htmlOutput("<br>"),
    actionButton("all",label="Show all"),
    htmlOutput("<br>"),
    actionButton("lang",label="Search by language")
),
 
  mainPanel(
    
    DT::dataTableOutput("maintab")
)))

server <- function(input, output) {
 
  output$maintab <- DT::renderDataTable(df)
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Run the app, only left side showing

Answer (score 0):

You have two identical `htmlOutput` id's that seem to be causing naming collision. Make them unique and your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

`htmlOutput` requires you have an output defined in the server. The first argument is an id, not raw HTML. Hence, as mentioned by the previous answer, having duplicate ids cause an error. If you want static, literal HTML use the `HTML` function in the ui

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  
  titlePanel("Idioms and Sayings"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel( 
      HTML("<br>"),
      actionButton("all",label="Show all"),
      HTML("<br>"),
      actionButton("lang",label="Search by language")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      
      DT::dataTableOutput("maintab")
    )))
```